# How to concatenate to a string from items in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to concatenate to a string. I begin with my string s, and I want to use a for loop to go through my dictionary. I know what I have makes no sense since I refer to 'i' in condition of the loop but never refer to in the body.

I have this

```
mydict1 = {
    'item_1': [7,19],
    'item_2': [0,3],
    'item_3': [54,191],
    'item_4': [41,43],
}

s = "Here are the items:" '\n'

for i in mydict1:
    s += key + ':' str(mydict1[1] - mydict1[0]) + ' bases long, spanning from bases ' + str(mydict1[0]) + ' to ' + str(mydict1[1])
print(s)
```

and I want this output:

```
Here are the items:
item_1: 12 bases long, spanning from bases 7 to 19
item_2: 3 bases long, spanning from bases 0 to 3
item_3: 137 bases long, spanning from bases 54 to 191
item_4: 2 bases long, spanning from bases 43 to 41
```

Comment: That's what you want – but what do you get?

Answer (score 7):

the best would be to use f-strings:

```
for key, (start, end) in mydict1.items():
    print(f'{key}: {end-start} bases long, spanning from bases {start} to {end}')
```

of course, with some changes, you can use also `str.format()` but it will be less readable.

To expand my answer with explanation what is wrong with your code:

- when you iterate over mydict1 like this `for i in mydict1:` you iterate over keys. so values of `i` will be keys of the dictionary
- `key` is not defines
- `mydict[0]` will cause KeyError, because there is no key 0, or 1

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.join()` method to join all elements of a list:

```py
mydict1 = {
    'item_1': [7, 19],
    'item_2': [0, 3],
    'item_3': [54, 191],
    'item_4': [41, 43],
}

base_str = "Here are the items: \n"
common_str = "bases long, spanning from bases"
out_out = base_str + \
          '\n'.join([f"{key}: {second - first} {common_str} {first} to {second}"
                     for key, (first, second) in mydict1.items()])

print(out_out)
```

**Output:**

```
Here are the items: 
item_1: 12 bases long, spanning from bases 7 to 19
item_2: 3 bases long, spanning from bases 0 to 3
item_3: 137 bases long, spanning from bases 54 to 191
item_4: 2 bases long, spanning from bases 41 to 43
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this approach, which uses string `format()`, does what you originally expected:

```
mydict1 = {
    'item_1': [7,19],
    'item_2': [0,3],
    'item_3': [54,191],
    'item_4': [41,43],
}

s = "Here are the items:" '\n'

for key, (start, end) in mydict1.items():
    s += '{}: {} bases long, spanning from bases {} to {}\n'.format(key, end-start, start, end)
print(s)
```

When the above code runs, the output is:

```
Here are the items:
item_1:12 bases long, spanning from bases 7 to 19
item_2:3 bases long, spanning from bases 0 to 3
item_3:137 bases long, spanning from bases 54 to 191
item_4:2 bases long, spanning from bases 41 to 43
```

Comment: given that there are different alternatives available - old style % formatting, str.format() method, f-string (fastest and most readable) to stick to OP approach (and maybe they don'tt know better) doesn't make sense

Comment: yes, now, my comment was when you used concatenation. Now edit also the start of your answer where you still refer to concatenation...